# Does R ignore variable name extensions starting with a dot in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, names

I have a data frame where some variable names include a "." extension. It seems R will ignore this extension and give me the variable anyway if I try to access it without the complete variable name. What is causing this/why does it happen? Below is a mini example of my problem.

```
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rlnorm(100)

data <- cbind.data.frame(y,x)

colnames(data) <- c("y.rnorm","x.rlnorm")

# these both return the same thing
data$y
data$y.rnorm
```

Comment: so does `data$y.r`, don't know why but I would avoid relying on that and always use the full column names.

Comment: and data$y.rn....does the $ operator go for a partial match if the name includes a  "."?

Comment: I don't think it's related to `.`...

Comment: I believe that R automatically grabs the column in the dataframe that starts with the portion of the name provided as long as it leads R to find a single field.  You'll find this isn't related to a '.' extension.  For example, data$y.r will also return data$y.rnorm.  If you had data$y.bin and data$y.norm, then data$y would return Null and you'd have to minimally provide data$y.r or data$y.b to get something returned.

Comment: This is coming up because I have some columns I apply bounds to and rename them with a ".bounded". In my function I forgot to change some of the variable names to include the ".bounded" extension, but the function accessed the variables anyway and I could not figure out how.

Comment: This is a good example of the tension in R between interactive and programmatic use. This partial matching behavior is one reason why many people will recommend that you (essentially) only use `[[` to select data frame columns when writing functions. Whereas the partial matching is a convenience when working quickly at the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R is setup to provide results to partial matches by design.

Read section [3.4 & 4.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) of the R language definition.

> **3.4.1** Character. The strings in `i` are matched against the names attribute of `x` and the resulting integers are used. For `[[` and `$` partial matching is used if exact matching fails, so `x$aa` will match `x$aabb` if `x` does not contain a component named "aa" and "aabb" is the only name which has prefix "aa". For `[[`, partial matching can be controlled via the exact argument which defaults to `NA` indicating that partial matching is allowed, but should result in a warning when it occurs. Setting exact to `TRUE` prevents partial matching from occurring, a `FALSE` value allows it and does not issue any warnings. Note that `[` always requires an exact match. The string `""` is treated specially: it indicates ‘no name’ and matches no element (not even those without a name). Note that partial matching is only used when extracting and not when replacing.

and

> **4.3.2** Partial matching on tags. Each remaining named supplied argument is compared to the remaining formal arguments using partial matching. If the name of the supplied argument matches exactly with the first part of a formal argument then the two arguments are considered to be matched. It is an error to have multiple partial matches. Notice that if `f <- function(fumble, fooey) fbody`, then `f(f = 1, fo = 2)` is illegal, even though the 2nd actual argument only matches `fooey`. `f(f = 1, fooey = 2)` is legal though since the second argument matches exactly and is removed from consideration for partial matching. If the formal arguments contain ‘...’ then partial matching is only applied to arguments that precede it.

#### update

As noted by [Uwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3817004/uwe), there may be a pending update to the R language definition as the behaviour of `[[` partial matching has changed. A look through [R News](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html) shows the following as *deprecated and defunct* with the 3.1.0 release:

> Partial matching when using the `$` operator on data frames now throws a warning and may become defunct in the future. If partial matching is intended, replace `foo$bar` by `foo[["bar", exact = FALSE]]`

Comment: Does the "." have anything to do with it?

Comment: No... the full stop has no impact

Comment: According to the  help page `?"[["` for R version 3.4.2, the default for the `exact` parameter is ***no** partial matching*. It seems, the language definition needs to be updated.

Comment: @Uwe, well spotted, I hadn't noticed the change. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` operator is designed to do partial matching. See [the *Subsetting* chapter of *Advanced R* by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html), Ctrl + F "partial matching":

> There’s one important difference between $ and [[. $ does partial matching:

```
x <- list(abc = 1)

x$a

## [1] 1

x[["a"]]

## NULL
```

> If you want to avoid this behaviour you can set the global option `warnPartialMatchDollar` to `TRUE`. Use with caution: it may affect behaviour in other code you have loaded (e.g., from a package).